# how to debug java app in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am developing a bluetooth application for blackberry. I am getting some BluetoothStateException's whil running the app on the phone. I am wondering if there is any way to debug th application on the phone?

Thanks.

UDPATE: There is an option in JDE I found to debug on device, but it keeps asking me to install signing keys.But I have not used any BB API's AFAIK

Answer (score 3):

You cant install a BB app on handset without signing it. Get a developer account on BlackBerry developer website, and you should be able to set up signing, it is almost trivial to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to sign if you haven't used the BlackBerry APIs that require signing keys.  In particular, the basic UiApplication class and the BluetoothStateException don't require the keys.

Having said that, it sounds like you used a protected API in there somewhere (they're really all over the place, the PersistentStore for example, or the Display class in the system package).  You can enable warnings within Eclipse for when you use protected APIs.  Under Window->Preferences->BlackBerry Java Plug-In, check the Warnings sub-item and make sure all 3 checkboxes are unchecked.  Then look at your Eclipse warnings/error view.

Also, I agree with @omermuhammed, it's really easy to get signing keys.

Comment: And if you really aren't using restricted APIs, then try just hitting cancel on the SignatureTool dialog and see if it still works.